# Compare two same fields with time difference in Views, using node revisions

Tags: 7, datetime, views, nodes

I'm trying to build a view containing two columns: first is the actual value of a (integer) field, second is the same field with its old value from two weeks before, using the revision. I suppose I would need a relationship for the second one but can't figure out how do to so.

The great Diff module help comparing one node at a time, but I would need to compare a list of nodes, reason why I want to do it in a view.

Any help would be more than welcome!

Comment: do you want all the values in the revision or just one value from two weeks before?

Comment: Would be the value from two weeks before, reason why I thought maybe it could be handle with a (date) relationship to the node revision... thanks for asking

Comment: Well actually if you have any solution to see all values maybe I could dig a bit more in this direction...

Comment: There's a view type for revisions instead of "content". Have you tried that? I've done similar to this before with the UI.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hackish solution.

What you need to do it create a field which would be unique per node on all the revisions. You could use the [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) instead of the normal field to crate this field and use the code below to computed the field

```
if (!$entity->nid) 
{
 node_save($entity);
}

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->nid;
```

This would set the value of the computed field to the nid of the node so that you dont have to bother about setting a unique value.

Now in the views create a view of the type content revision. (This would be done by selecting content revision from the dropdown near **Show**

Add the fields for which you want the revision data. Use the one which says  **(historical data)** at the end of it.

Now add the contextual filter with the computed field we created earlier. make sure the select the one with **(historical data)** at the end of it.

In the filters you can choose **Content revision: Updated date** and select the date range you want. you can also provide relative values such as -7 days to get the all the values before 7 days.

The computed field was used because I was not able to get the nid of the revisions. If any one has a work around on that please do make the required changes.